# Comparing two dictionaries with numpy arrays as values

Tags: python

I'm writing tests using `pytest`. I have two dictionaries with `numpy` arrays that looks something like:

```py
dict_1 = {
    'test_1': np.array([-0.1, -0.2, -0.3]),
    'test_2': np.array([-0.4, -0.5, -0.6]),
    'test_3': np.array([-0.7, -0.8, -0.9]),
}
```

When I try to compare two of these using `assert dict_1 == dict_2`, I get an error saying

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

And it seems like `any()` and `all()` only work on lists. Would I have to run a loop in those two dicts and compare each values using `all()` or `any()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.testing.assert_equal`:

```
np.testing.assert_equal(dict_1,dict_2)
```

For more information, [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_equal.html) is a link to the `numpy` documentation for `np.testing.assert_equal`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check to make sure that the key sets are equal, and then make sure that, for each key, the elements in the corresponding arrays are the same using a generator comprehension and `.all()`:

```py
assert dict_1.keys() == dict_2.keys() and \
    all((dict_1[key] == dict_2[key]).all() for key in dict_1.keys())
```